# Why I can't reach array pointer defined in struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have following struct:

```
typedef struct PCB_struct
    {
        Boolean valid;
        pid_t pid;
        pid_t ppid;
        unsigned ownerID;
        unsigned start;
        unsigned duration;
        unsigned usedCPU;
        processType_t type;
        status_t status;
        simInfo_t simInfo;
        unsigned size;              // size of logical process memory in pages
        int maxActivePages;
        int currActivePages;
        int activePages[maxActivePages];
        pageTableEntry_t *pageTable;
    } PCB_t;
```

This stuct will be initialized in method-call

```
void resetPCB (PCB_t *pcb)
{
    pcb->valid = FALSE;         
    pcb->pid = 0; 
    pcb->ppid = 0; 
    pcb->ownerID = 0;
    pcb->start = 0; 
    pcb->duration = 0; 
    pcb->usedCPU = 0; 
    pcb->type = foreground; 
    pcb->status = init;
    // pcb->simInfo;    // currently unused, 
                        // placeholder, but is not initialised
    pcb->size = 0;      // process has no physical memory allocated
    pcb->pageTable = NULL;
    pcb->maxActivePages = 2;
    pcb->currActivePages = 0;
    pcb->activePages = { 0 }; // this doesn't work
}
```

But for some reason I can't reach an array `int activePages[maxActivePages]`, when I define a pointer to that struct. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and error details.

Comment: is `maxActivePages` a `#define`d constant? You can't have a VLA as a struct member. You **can** have a FAM instead as the last member of the struct.

Comment: Added method, where it should be initialized

Comment: @EvheniiVasylenko makes it an exact dupe ... (well, almost, you can't **assign** to an array either)

Comment: What means FAM?